# How to access values stored in a Java multidimensional array from a C program using JNI?

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

Say we have a multidimensional Java array `int arr[][] = new int[5][10];` and we pass this array to a C program using JNI as an object of type `jobject` (it has to be of this type). One detail to take into account is that the dimensions of the array to pass to C are not fixed (i.e. sometimes, the array has 2 dimensions, sometimes 3 or 4).

From this C program how can we print all the values stored in the Java multidimensional array? I have searched the web on how this could be solved but without success. Any pointers will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is explained in the JNI Programmers Guide and Specification by Shen Liang.  You should be able to download a PDF copy from the internet.  There is a full example in section 3.3.5 - accessing arrays of objects.

Comment: Take a look here: https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipes/recipeNo026